# Creating calculations using SQLite and C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am developing a small time-management app (so that I can learn C#/WPF).  I need to know the best way to return calculations to various textblocks on one of my forms.

I have a table called "tblActivity" and I need to calculate how many times certain values exist.  In the old days of VBA, I would have simply used DSum or DCount, but I'm not sure as the the most efficient/correct/fastest way to return this sort of data (the fields are indexed by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to query the table as a whole you would do something like this:

```
int rowCount = tblActivity.rows.count();
```

if you want the count where a column meets certain criteria, run a select statement

```
datarow[] SelectedIndexCountROw = tblActivity.select("Index = 12 AND Index2 = 'something'");
```

what you can still do if you need to display the data and the count

```
int COunt;
foreach row as datarow in tblActivity.rows
{
string ValueFromTable = row("Column");


//display data if you must,
COunt += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jonny - so if I wanted to create a count of all of the [Activities] = 'Running" or 'Sitting'.  I'd simply create a query to return the value.

Comment: Thats it :) Best of luck